# What is the correct way of getting the value of a selected drop down item using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-select

I thought i knew this, and now I'm quite embarassed becuase I don't :-/

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BuqHB/) demonstrates two ways of getting the value of a selected drop down item in JavaScript. Code reproduced here:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("test");
alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);  //like this
alert(obj.value);  //or like this
```

Quirksmode suggests that some older broswers don't support the latter (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html), and value isn't a supported attribute in the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6).

So I wondered, which is the correct standarised way of doing this?

Anyone?

Comment: I have always used the first method. I thought that was the better way. It works in every browser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David is correct. If you want full compatibility you might want to use something like:

```
var options = document.getElementById('securityWalkInTime').children;
var value = [];
for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++) {
    var option = options[i];
    if (option.selected === true) {
        value.push(option.value ? option.value : option.text);
    }
}
```

This will definitely work, however, for all practical cases I would use the latter of your example.

Comment: I had a look at jQuery, your approach is broadly similar to their handling.

Answer (score 1):

Both are [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980). Use the version with better browser support.

> value isn't a supported attribute in the HTML 4.01 spec

This is [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), not HTML.